# which .net assembly implements int[]. string[] etc

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I wonder which .net assembly implements the array keyword []

For example:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
string[] arrString = new string[6];
```

Comment: `typeof(int[]).Assembly`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mscorlib`

The base type is `Array` class.